# Angular 4 - render template from string variable holding template

Tags: angular, typescript, rendering

How to render a html using a string variable (holding template) - Angular4.

**sample.component.ts**

```
let stringTemplate = "<div><p>I should be rendered as a HTML<br></p></div>";
```

**sample.component.html** should be rendered based on elements in variable **stringTemplate**

NOTE: **stringTemplate** is not static. Will be getting its data from server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind to the innerHtml property.

```html
  <div [innerHtml]="stringTemplate"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Is this the only way to display? Any other alternatives you know?

Comment: I found a similar question.. You can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding